# Spree Order checkout_flow not transitioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, spree

Order checkout flow is not transitioning when I have a order decorator file in my app folder.

```
 # app/models/spree/order_decorator.rb
 Spree::Order.class_eval do
   checkout_flow do
       go_to_state :payment, if: ->(order) { order.payment? || order.payment_required? }
       go_to_state :complete
    end
 end
```

It only works when I move the order decorator file to lib folder and require the file in initializers folder.

```
   # lib/models/spree/order_decorator.rb
  Spree::Order.class_eval do
   checkout_flow do
       go_to_state :payment, if: ->(order) { order.payment? || order.payment_required? }
       go_to_state :complete
    end
 end

  # config/initializers/spree.rb
  require "#{Rails.root}/lib/models/spree/order_decorator"
```

Environment

```
Version used: Spree 3.3.6
*Ruby version: 2.5.3
*Rails version: 5.1.7
```

In application.rb

```
  # config/application.rb
   config.to_prepare do
        # Load application's model / class decorators
       Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/**/*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
        Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
       end

       # Load application's view overrides
       Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/overrides/*.rb")) do |c|
        Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
       end
   end
```